# EXCEL VBA, Multiple consolidation range. Can't Change the refence to sheet from name to index

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

Here something I cannot figure out.

I am creating a pivot from multiple ranges on a new sheet.

This works:

```
arr = Array(Array("US!R6C2:R17C23", "US"), Array("Japan!R6C2:R17C23", "Japan"), Array( _
    "Other1!R6C2:R17C23", "Other1"), Array("Other2!R6C2:R17C23", "Other2"), Array( _
    "EU!R6C2:R17C23", "EU"))
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:=arr, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "", TableName:="PivotTable9", _
    DefaultVersion:=6
```

This does not work:

```
arr = Array(Array(Worksheets(2).Range("B6:W17"), "US"), Array("Japan!R6C2:R17C23", "Japan"), Array( _
    "Other1!R6C2:R17C23", "Other1"), Array("Other2!R6C2:R17C23", "Other2"), Array( _
    "EU!R6C2:R17C23", "EU"))ere
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:=arr, Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "", TableName:="PivotTable9", _
    DefaultVersion:=6
```

The difference is in how I try to reference the first part:

```
Array(Worksheets(2).Range("B6:W17"), "US"))
```

vs

```
Array("US!R6C2:R17C23", "US")
```

Any help to understand why I can't make this change and what I need to do instead would be great.

Comment: I'm guessing it needs to be of the form worksheet name (as string) - exclamation mark - address (as string). Why are you not just using the first formulation?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the:

```
Array(Worksheets(2).Range("B6:W17"), "US"))
```

To:

```
Array(Chr(34) &Worksheets(2).Name &"!" & Worksheets(2).Range("B6:W17").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & Chr(34), "US")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd steer clear of using the Consolidation method to create PivotTables...it has quite a few limitations, and at the same time better alternatives exist, including:

1. Using VBA to mash all your data from seperate tables into one table. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47279374/2507160
2. Using PowerQuery to do the same. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47170312/2507160