# VBA - Source data from multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel, charts, excel-charts

I am attempting to create a new chart using source data from multiple sheets.  The data will always be in the same column no matter the sheet.  However, I would like to select the data from `Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))` from each of the sheets following the permanent two sheets at the beginning.

The sheets that I want data extracted from will be used as source data for a chart that will be created and deleted as new sheets are added, and the cycle will be repeated.

So, for example, I would like it to grab data from sheets 3 to 52, or however many there are, from the range specified above so it becomes one cohesive source.  I am not sure if there is a nice way to do this without using a hidden sheet.  Thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Locations()
Set Build = Charts.Add(After = Worksheets("Report"))
    With Build
        .SetSourceData
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: (You're missing `End With`)

Comment: @BruceWayne - I apologize, it is extremely unfinished, I was simply providing what I have so far.

Comment: Presumably you have more than one column if you are intending on plotting on 2 axes? Or will one be left to default to 1,2,3 etc?

Comment: @QHarr - Yes, The X-Axis will be the names of the buildings and the Y-Axis will be the number of times the buildings name was used in a cell within the range

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I think your question is going to need more info if you want a decent answer, based on that last comment. Do you mean a histogram by building name? And range being the entire joined dataset? I note your code shows clusteredcolumn.

Comment: @SJR -  A method for creating a source data from multiple sheets that are finite

Comment: @QHarr - If I am understanding your questions correctly, yes that is what I am looking for

Comment: If you are certain of sheet order you can loop from 3 to sheets.count (only 2 preceeding worksheets) calling a sub that extracts the required range and pastes to next available row in "master" consolidation range. Then another sub to create the chart. Otherwise loop checking sheet names not like A or B (the two you want to exclude).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to simplify the situation by using a hidden sheet

```
Private Sub Locations()

Dim ws As Worksheet, rep As Worksheet, LastRow As Double
With ThisWorkbook
    For n = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Set ws = Worksheets(n)
        Set rep = Worksheets("Report")
        LastRow = rep.Range("C1", rep.Range("C1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
        If IsNumeric(ws.Name) Then
            If rep.Range("C1") = "" Then
                ws.Range("F2", ws.Range("F2").End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Destination:=rep.Range("C1")
            Else:
                ws.Range("F2", ws.Range("F2").End(xlDown)).Copy _
                Destination:=rep.Range("C" & LastRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next n
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the code that would loop through Sheet3 onwards and add all the data from column B (excluding the header) to an array, then you can use the array to plot the values into your chart?

```
Sub foo()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Myarray() As Variant
y = 0

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        If ws.Name <> "Sheet2" Then
             LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
             Counter = Counter + LastRow
             ReDim Preserve Myarray(Counter)
             For Each cell In ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
                 Myarray(y) = cell.Value
                 y = y + 1
             Next cell
        End If
    End If
Next ws
```

If you then want to write the contents of the array into a helper sheet:

```
Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Temp"
For p = 1 To UBound(Myarray)
    Sheets("Temp").Cells(p, 1).Value = Myarray(p - 1)
Next p
```

Then find the last row and get the range into SetSourceData to update the chart.

Comment: How would you plot values stored in an array?

Comment: Personally I would probably place the values from the array into another Sheet and then use that range to plot the chart, alternatively there are some ways to plot straight from an Array, none of which I have ever used, but this might be of use for you: [link]https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/388319/excel-vba-array-to-range-for-setsourcedata[/link]

Comment: I've just found this Q, might be useful - my first thought was also to transfer the array into a helper sheet, but it seems it can be done directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570023/create-chart-from-array-data-and-not-range

Answer (score 0):

If you've got Excel 2016 or later, then the new PowerQuery functionality under the 'Get & Transform' section of the Data tab is perfect for this. (In previous versions, PowerQuery is available as a free addin from Microsoft that you'll have to install).

See the following link for an example of how it can be used to mash up data from multiple worksheets:
[excel indirect function to read dates and return dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164451/excel-indirect-function-to-read-dates-and-return-dynamic-values/47170312#47170312)
From there, it's a simple task to make a PivotTable and then PivotChart out of it, and it can automatically bring through new worksheets without the user having to make any changes.