# Excel: newest status of item over all sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

At work, I use one excel workbook per customer to keep track of all the open issues (on the first sheet). For every on-site appointment, I create a new sheet (named YYYYMMDD) on which I record all my changes. Every change references the issue ID from the first sheet, has a status before and after and some explanation about the change. Obviously, the first sheet *also* has a status column and I'd like to automatically calculate that based on the appointment sheets (get the newest one). Seems doable, but somehow I always find myself in a dead end.

edit
Mockup screenshots of the two sheet types
[main sheet (overview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xUIq.png)
[report sheet (one per appointment)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0NvC.png)

`Main!C3` should contain the newest status for Issue #002, i.e. the most recent 'status after' in the report sheets for that ID.
/edit

My approach:
Calculate an increasing value per change, something like

```
sheet_id*10000+row*100+status_id
```

(I always have <100 entries per appointment and <10 status types), then use `MAX IF` over all sheets and finally `MOD(X,10)` to extract the status. Unfortunately, IF can't handle 3D-references, so I tried using `GET.WORKBOOK(1)` and then `INDIRECT`, but then `MAX` somehow doesn't seem to support that. I also messed around with some different array calculation but to no avail. Same story with `INDEX MATCH`. I'm pretty sure `MAXIFS` would work, but unfortunately, that is not a thing in the version of Excel I'm using.

Has anyone done this before? Any help appreciated :)

PS: using VBA isn't really an option (which also means that I'd prefer 3D-refs over GET.WORKBOOK(1))

Comment: Could you mock up a quick "before/after" screenshot please to help explain what you are trying to achieve here? I'm struggling to follow you from text alone.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor yeah sorry, it's all a bit vague. Added two screenshots, hopefully they help.

Comment: @jeffreyweir 2016, which should, according to many sites, have the MAXIFS, but it doesn't.

Comment: Reason I ask is to see whether PowerQuery aka Get & Transform is an option. Which it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that the simplest and most robust way of fulfilling these requirements is to use PowerQuery (aka Data>Get & Transform) to dynamically pull all the data from each sheet into the Data Model, and then create a PivotTable from the Data Model that shows the exact thing you have in your screenshot.

You can see how simple it is to achieve this at my answer to another question here: [excel indirect function to read dates and return dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164451/excel-indirect-function-to-read-dates-and-return-dynamic-values/47170312#47170312)

Comment: PowerQuery, Excel is full of surprises :D Sounds interesting, I'll have time to check it out on the weekend. Thanks!

Comment: PQ is a quiet revolution. Ken Puls has a great book out on it.