# VBA, Copy and Paste Sheet to Sheet, Copying unwanted headers

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that

1) finds headers in sheet 1

2) finds headers in sheet 2

3) matches the headers between sheets and copys and pastes the data of the like headers from sheet 1 to 2.

4) I have an option if the headers from sheet 1 exists in "Mappings" sheet then change the header to what I have in the mappings then do the copy and paste.

It works fine the first time I do this between sheet 1 and sheet 2. (although my sheet 1 doesnt need the mappings tab) . When I try this code again directly after with another sheet (that does use mappings tab) , I get some headers copying over, when its not supposed to copy the headers only the data that is beneath the headers.

```
+------+------------+------+--+
| Col1 |    Col2    | Col3 |  |
+------+------------+------+--+
| Col1 | normaldata | Col3 |  |
|      | normaldata |      |  |
|      | normaldata |      |  |
+------+------------+------+--+
```

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub importtodatabase(from_ws, to_ws)
    Dim rng As Range, trgtCell As Range
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim trgt As Worksheet
    Set src = Worksheets(from_ws)
    Set trgt = Worksheets(to_ws)
    Dim row_num As Integer
    Dim Max_row_data As Integer
    Dim source_tab As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets(to_ws).Select
    Max_row_data = get_max_row("")

    If Max_row_data <> 2 Then
        Max_row_data = Max_row_data + 1
    End If

    Sheets("Mappings").Select
    max_row = get_max_row("")


    With src
        For Each rng In Intersect(.Rows(1), .UsedRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            For row_num = 2 To max_row
                If from_ws = Range("BU" & row_num).value Then
                    If rng = Range("BV" & row_num).value Then
                        rng = Range("BW" & row_num).value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next row_num

            Set trgtCell = trgt.Rows(1).Find(rng.value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)



                If Not trgtCell Is Nothing Then
                    .Range(rng.Offset(1), .Cells(.Rows.count, rng.Column).End(xlUp)).copy
                    With trgt
                        .Cells(Max_row_data, trgtCell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    End With
                End If
            'End If
        Next rng
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Get Max Row function:

```
Public Function get_max_row(tab_name, Optional col_srch, Optional include_shapes As Boolean = True, Optional include_border = False)

    Dim max_shape_row As Long: max_shape_row = 0
    Dim max_shape_loc As Double: max_shape_loc = 0

    If IsMissing(col_srch) Then
        col_srch = ""
    End If

    old_tab = ActiveSheet.Name

    If tab_name = "" Then
        tab_name = old_tab
    End If
    select_tab = tab_name

    Sheets(select_tab).Select

    On Error GoTo errorHandler
    max_row_num1 = Sheets(select_tab).Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
    On Error GoTo 0

    'max_row_num2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    max_row_num2 = 2

    'QuickMessage (max_row_num1 & "-" & max_row_num2)

    If max_row_num1 > max_row_num2 Then
        get_max_row = max_row_num1
    Else
        get_max_row = max_row_num2
    End If

    If col_srch <> "" Then
        ref_srch_row = get_max_row

        Do While ref_srch_row > 1
            If Range(col_srch & ref_srch_row).value <> "" Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            ref_srch_row = ref_srch_row - 1
        Loop

        get_max_row = ref_srch_row
    End If

    If include_shapes = True Then
        max_text_row = get_max_row

        shapes_num = IsEmpty(Sheets(tab_name).Shapes)

        If shapes_num = False Then
            For Each Item In Sheets(tab_name).Shapes
                'Debug.Print Item.Name & ":" & Item.Top & ":" & Item.Height

                curr_shape_loc = Item.Top + Item.Height

                max_shape_loc = IIf(curr_shape_loc > max_shape_loc, curr_shape_loc, max_shape_loc)
            Next Item

            For Each cell In Sheets(tab_name).Columns("A:A").Cells
                curr_cell_loc = cell.Top

                If curr_cell_loc > max_shape_loc Then
                    max_shape_row = cell.row
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next cell

            get_max_row = IIf(max_shape_row > max_text_row, max_shape_row, max_text_row)
        End If
    End If

    'check border
    If include_border = True Then
        On Error Resume Next
        count_num = 0
        For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
            count_num = count_num + 1
            If cell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlNone Then
                get_max_row = Application.Max(max_shape_row, max_text_row, cell.row)
            End If

            If count_num > 10000 Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    Sheets(old_tab).Select

    Exit Function

errorHandler:
    get_max_row = 1
    Resume Next
End Function
```

Comment: You need to switch ScreenUpdating to True at the end and also include the function get_max_row.. If you had Option Explicit at the top of your code it would prompt you on this. And using .Select slows your code down horribly, don't use it (only in very few circumstances is it useful and necessary).

Comment: You also have missing variable declarations and implicit data types used where you want explicit. For example, the sub signature looks like it is expecting strings but uses variants. Showing some sample data for both sheets and the mapping table would help and definitely this mysterious missing function ;-)

Comment: 1) Your code is so convoluted that it is difficult to give anything more than pointers. I agree with QHarr that you need to include the `get_max_row` function. 2) Why are you using copy/paste when you're only pasting values? It would make more sense, e.g. if you needed to keep the formatting. You can simply set the destination range for the copied data to be inserted as a parameter in the `copy` function. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel).

Comment: Without data the logic of If from_ws = Range("BU" & row_num).Value Then
                    If rng = Range("BV" & row_num).Value Then    is really hard to follow..... it feels like you think you are using Mappings sheet but actually your With statement means that you are using src. Try qualifying Range("BU" & row_num)  and the others with the sheet name in front. I think you wanted Sheets("Mappings").Range("BU" & row_num) etc....to avoid any confusion. You can then drop the Select for that sheet. Sorry, lots of guess work here.

Comment: Hey excelguy...how 'bout you answer the comments that your question has generated.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've added the get max row function. I'll get some sample data as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to consolidate data from different sheets or ranges, then in order to significantly simplify your code and at the same time make it much more robust (to things like row insertion) I'd suggest making each of your source ranges into Excel Tables using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut, and then using one of these approaches:

- Using VBA to mash all your data from seperate tables into one table. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47279374/2507160
- Using PowerQuery to do the same. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47170312/2507160